# Scrollbars not showing on WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf

I'm having a real hard time figuring this one out. I have a DataGrid within a Grid. The column headers (and rows) are extending beyond the visible area. I've tried a combination of things, such as setting the Width, Height and HorizontalScrollBarVisibility. I still can't get scrollbars to appear. Here's the xaml I've been working with

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                          Grid.RowSpan="4"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          Height="278"
                          Width="300"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          Margin="0,0,0,6"></DataGrid>
```

Comment: What are the `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` of the `Grid` that this `DataGrid` is contained within?

Comment: The Grid has 4 columns and 8 rows. The first row has a height of 40.

Comment: What about the other columns and rows? What are their height and width settings?

Comment: They're not set. Just empty elements. <ColumnDefinition /> <RowDefinition />

Comment: First paste whole xaml, your issue may have it's origin somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

try not setting the height/width, the grid columns/rows might not be big enough for the specified size.  if you need a specific size specify it in the Grid definition.